# Calling python function with optional paramenter

Tags: python, pandas, function, csv

I am trying to build a function, where I want to read a CSV file and want to see either top 10 rows or last 10 rows. In the function I will pass file name and top row number or last row number. The code I have right now is here,

```
import pandas as pd

def read_file(file_name,top_rows=0,down_rows=0):
    if top_rows == top_rows:
        top = read.head(top_rows)
        return(top)

    if down_rows == down_rows:
        down = read.tail(down_rows)
        return(down)
```

When I am calling function with top_row parameter the function shows the output.

```
read_file(file_name.csv,top_rows=10)
```

But with the down_row parameter its not showing any output.

```
read_file(file_name.csv,down_rows=10)
```

Am I missing anything or do I have any mistakes in my code?

Comment: First U have typos, when U call it you forget "s" for rows, also this makes No Sense: if top_rows == top_rows this will Always true same for bottom_rows if

Comment: doesn't `top_rows == top_rows`  always result in `True`?  Did you want `if top_rows:` or `if top_rows != 0:`

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for your comment, its was a typing mistake.

Comment: @jonson Just fix your "If statments" and u are fine 

Comment: Why are u Return with ()?

Comment: @Christoph What is "u"?

Comment: @Christoph Please write "you" when that's what you mean.

Comment: @JonSG I was also thinking about this 1st if statement, its all time true. That my mistake. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check if `top_rows` or `down_rows` are non-zero.

```
import pandas as pd

def read_file(file_name, top_rows=0, down_rows=0):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    
    if top_rows:
        return data.head(top_rows)
    
    if down_rows:
        return data.tail(down_rows)
```

Comment: You could just use `if top_rows:` which is the preferred style.

Comment: Thanks for improvement @user19077881, updated with same.